# Imprimir nombre de usuario en PHP despues de login

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, login

Tengo el siguiente problema. Para loguear un usuario, seleccioné la opción de correo electrónico. Sin embargo, en la base de datos también se incluye un nombre de usuario al momento del registro. Mi problema es que al imprimir un "Bienvenido, (nombre de usuario)" se imprime la dirección de correo electrónico y no el nombre de usuario. Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de poder hacer que se imprima el nombre de usuario trayéndolo desde la base de datos o si la única opción es modificando el login para que el usuario ingrese con su nombre de usuario (en vez de su correo).

Adjunto el código:

**LOGIN .PHP**

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    include 'conexion_be.php';

    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $pass = hash('sha512', $pass);

    $validar_login = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and pass='$pass'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($validar_login) > 0){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $correo;
        header("location: ../bienvenida.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Usuario no encontrado!","Por favor verifica los datos introducidos e intentá nuevamente.","error").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'../registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

**ARCHIVO .HTML DEL FORMULARIO DE LOGIN**

```
div class="contenedor__login-register">
                    <!--Login-->
                    <form action="php/login_usuario_be.php" method="POST" class="formulario__login">
                        <h2>Iniciar Sesión</h2>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" name="correo">
                        <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="passwordLog" minlength="4" maxlength="16" name="pass">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                    <button id="show_passwordLog" class="btn btn-primaryLog" type="button" onclick="mostrarPasswordLog()"> <span class="fa fa-eye icon"></span> </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <button class="Entrar">Entrar</button>
                        <a class="forgot" href="#">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                    </form>
```

**ARCHIVO DONDE IMPRIMO EL "BIENVENIDO (NOMBRE DE USUARIO)"**

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
    }
?>

<?php include_once 'includes/templates/headeraccess.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bienvenida</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="seccion contenedor home">
            <div class="contenedorLeft">
                <h2 class="title">Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="contenedorRight">
            <a href="php/cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
            </div>
        </section>
</body>
</html>

<?php include_once 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Cambia  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $correo; por $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($validar_login); $user = $row[‘usuario’]; y el en el html pones bienvenido <?php echo $user ?>

Comment: Gracias. Tengo un inconveniente. Al cambiar el $_SESSION['usuario`] esta parte del código me queda obsoleta: <?php

    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
    }

?> Como podria cambiarla con tu codigo?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba asi a ver que tal..

```
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
    }

    $user = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $wel = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$user'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wel); 
    
    $usuario = $row['usuario'];
    
    echo 'Bienvenido: '.$usuario.'';
```

Comment: Pues intenté con eso y nada. Me detecta el código como si no hubiera iniciado sesión, y eso hace saltar el alert. Me está sacando canas verdes esto, ya no se como mas intentar! :@